# Textblock textwrapping not working

Tags: wpf, textblock, word-wrap, datagridtemplatecolumn

Can somebody give me an idea of why the Wrapping is not working inide these Textblocks?
I just don't know why, i changed all my stackpanels to grids to avoid the infinite space issue, but still it doesn't work...

```
<Border x:Name="SummaryRightSideContainerBorder" Grid.Column="1"
        Margin="10,10,10,10" BorderBrush="Black"
        BorderThickness="1">
    <ContentControl x:Name="SummaryRightSideContainerContentControl" Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=SummaryTreeView}">
        <ContentControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelsProject:ProjectViewModel}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Displaying Project DataContract stuff..." />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelsProject:SequenceViewModel}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Displaying Sequence DataContract stuff..." />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelsProject:GroupViewModel}">
                <StackPanel>


                    <DataGrid Margin="10" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                  Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"
                                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                                  CellStyle="{DynamicResource dgCellStyle}"
                                  ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource dgHeader}"
                                  DataContext="{Binding ElementName=SummaryTreeView,
                                                        Path=SelectedItem}"
                                  GridLinesVisibility="None"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Standards}"
                                  Padding="0" RowHeaderWidth="0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                        <DataGrid.Resources>
                            <Style x:Key="dgHeader" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                            <TextBlock Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                                                           Padding="5"
                                                           Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                           TextAlignment="Left">
                                                    <TextBlock.Background>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                                            <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#373638" />
                                                            <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#77797B" />
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </TextBlock.Background>
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
                                <Setter Property="Background">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                            <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#373638" />
                                            <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#77797B" />
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                            <Style x:Key="dgCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGrid.Resources>
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Standards">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>


                                        <Grid Margin="5">
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition />
                                                <RowDefinition />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=StepMaster.Description}" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                                            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition />
                                                    <RowDefinition />
                                                    <RowDefinition />
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Standard: " VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Standard}" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>

                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Details: " VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Details}" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>

                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Comments: " VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Comments}" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Grid>

                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>


                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelsProject:StepViewModel}">
                <UniformGrid Rows="3">
                    <TextBlock Margin="10" FontWeight="DemiBold"
                               Text="Standards" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="10" FontWeight="DemiBold"
                               Text="Standards Details" />
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <DataGrid Margin="10" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                            <Another data grid is here />
                        </DataGrid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </UniformGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentControl.Resources>
    </ContentControl>
</Border>
```

Comment: Set all the RowDefinition Height="Auto".  Try a hard width <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>  Not as a final answer but to see what happens.

Comment: It wraps now using <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>, but I don't wanna put a fixed Width on that column, because the user might wanna expand the window and it would look "funny"...

Comment: I suppose it can be caused by `<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />` try to change this `Width` to a `*` or a specific value as *Carlos H* suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the only way to make this work is to use properties directly in the DataGrid:

```
MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=SummaryRightSideContainerBorder, Path=ActualWidth}" ColumnWidth="*"
```

MaxWidth is used so that the Datagrid itself does not exceed its container boundaries and ColumnWidth is used so that the columns use 100% of the space available in the datagrid.

Blam's answer put me in the right track to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

As an answer you need to set second column to

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
```

so it is constrained.  * mean the size of the container.  Right now it is growing outside the container (screen)

first column auto is OK

Comment: I thought this would work but it didn't, as soon as I changed the second column width from "200" to "*" it stopped wrapping again...  Maybe it's the TemplateColumn disturbing the normal behavior of the grids, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I just posted my full xaml, how do I give points to a person here??

Comment: Pretty sure the problem is that the column width is not constrained.  Put a Width="*" on the DataGrid.  Give points by clicking the up arrrow.